# switched from webform to mvc and now can't have android contacting localhost

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webview

I have a test application that I wrote back in the days. I used simple asp.net webforms application to perform login to the android application.
Now I rewrite the asp.net application using mvc, I changed the former url string from

```
<string name="web_login_page">http://10.0.2.2:51469/blabla.com/Account/Android/LoginDroid.aspx</string>
```

to

```
<string name="web_login_page">http://10.0.2.2:52707/Account/Login</string>
```

run the java code

```
String urlToLoginPage = getString(R.string.web_login_page);

webview.loadUrl(urlToLoginPage);
```

and now Android's webView throws:

> Bad request - invalid hostname
>
> http error 400. the request hostname is invalid.

Tried to play with it a bit with no success. Does anybody know the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
<string name="web_login_page">http://10.0.2.2:52707/Account/Login</string>
```

With

```
<string name="web_login_page">http://your_machine_ip_address/Account/Login</string>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this, with no success. Any other ideas? Maybe it's becuase of the MVC form of url, i.e. without the domain 'blabla.com' in the url.